# Expanding rows of data

Tags: r, dplyr, expand, tidyr

I have an issue of expanding rows of my data frame. I tried `expand` from `tidyr` inside of a `dplyr` chain. The point is that it seems that this function is expanding the data but by changing the order of expand element which is not desired. I want to keep order of `sp` column after expand.

Here is my attempt

```
df <- data.frame(label1=letters[1:6],label2=letters[7:12])

sp <- c(-1,0,seq(0.1,0.5,0.1),seq(-2,-2.5,-0.1),seq(0.1,0.5,0.1))
sp
#     [1] -1.0  0.0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5 -2.0 -2.1 -2.2 -2.3 -2.4 -2.5  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

    expanded <- df%>%
      expand(df,sp)

> head(expanded)
  label1 label2   sp
1      a      g -2.5
2      a      g -2.4
3      a      g -2.3
4      a      g -2.2
5      a      g -2.1
6      a      g -2.0
```

I want to expand `df` based on `sp` order. how can we do that?

expected output

```
label1 label2   sp
1       a      g -1.0
2       a      g  0.0
3       a      g  0.1
4       a      g  0.2
5       a      g  0.3
6       a      g  0.4
7       a      g  0.5
8       a      g  -2
9       a      g  -2.1
10      a      g  -2.2
11      a      g  -2.3
12      a      g  -2.4
13      a      g  -2.5
14      b      h  -1.0
15      b      h   0.0
16      b      h   0.1
```

---

and so on

Comment: what is your desired o/p?

Comment: Desired output is in the question but the order of sp is not correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `match` the column 'sp' with the vector `sp` in the global environment to do the ordering

```
r1 <- df %>%
         expand(df, sp) %>%
         arrange(label1, label2, match(sp, unique(.GlobalEnv$sp)))
dim(r1)
#[1] 78  3


identical(unique(r1$sp), unique(sp))
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

If there are duplicates in the 'sp' `vector` and we want to `expand` on all the values, one option is to do the expansion on the sequence of the `vector` and later change the values

```
r2 <- df %>%
        expand(df, sp=seq_along(sp)) %>% 
        mutate(sp = .GlobalEnv$sp[sp])


dim(r2)
#[1] 108   3

head(r2, length(sp))
#    label1 label2   sp
# 1       a      g -1.0
# 2       a      g  0.0
# 3       a      g  0.1
# 4       a      g  0.2
# 5       a      g  0.3
# 6       a      g  0.4
# 7       a      g  0.5
# 8       a      g -2.0
# 9       a      g -2.1
# 10      a      g -2.2
# 11      a      g -2.3
# 12      a      g -2.4
# 13      a      g -2.5
# 14      a      g  0.1
# 15      a      g  0.2
# 16      a      g  0.3
# 17      a      g  0.4
# 18      a      g  0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Now it seems that the order is corrected but what about expanding each row with whole sp. Desired output is in the question but the order is not correct!

Comment: @Alexander It is expanding with whole sp, If you look at the `identical`, I am just taking the `unique` elements of the column which will be the same order as in the 'sp' vector

Comment: Ok I just understand your solution. Later on I can do grouping and arrange the `sp` column. Thanks Man! I appreciated it!

Comment: Oh I am really sorry in my real data there is something happen. There is a lets say repeat in the elements `sp`  `seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)`. I modified the question and added this part. In this sense, repeated elements disappeared from the output of `expanded` . So this is the trouble now!

Comment: It seems that the last `seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)` is not repeating in the r1.:(

Comment: @Alexander I checked the dimensions of your output and mine.  It is `dim(r1)
#[1] 78  3
; dim(expanded)
#[1] 78  3`

Comment: @Alexander I think the `expand` will do the expansion on the unique elements, but your vector have duplicates. i.e. `expanded <- df%>% expand(df, sp[1:13]);
 dim(expanded)
#[1] 78  3`

Comment: @Alexander I think even if you add those rows, it will be just duplicate rows, do you really want that?  In that case, just `rbind` the filtered rows from 'r1' based on the last piece of seq elements to the 'r1'

Comment: this `sp` sequence is very important in my real data. So, yes it is required.

Comment: @Alexander In that case `r1 %>% filter(sp %in% seq(0.1,0.5,0.1)) %>% bind_rows(r1, .)`

Comment: @ I guess I should asked the question how to expand data with duplicated vectors. But anyway your answer is solved my trouble so far. Thanks!